# API to get a provisioning profile from Apple dev site

Tags: ios, ios4, continuous-integration

I'm wondering if it's possible to get the latest provisioning profile from Apple Developer Portal using API? 
I've set up CI for iOS project but I have to update provisioning profile manually every time when it is changed so I'd be glad to automate this process as well.
Thanks

Comment: No a direct answer to your question but a good reference for a CLI Ruby utility that interfaces with the developer portal (via HTML scrapping) https://github.com/whatupdave/wod.git

Comment: Newer xcode releases are able to download profiles from the dev portal, so I guess there's an API. I hadn't yet the time to do some reverse engineering but it should be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid not.  You should be able to get it done by scraping the HTML, but that's about it.  Apple are terrible when it comes to the web (client-side excepted).

Comment: Xcode somehow can manage the team provisioning profile so I assume there is some API which is most likely private

Comment: @Dmytro I have actually done a dump of the traffic, but of course it's  encrypted. I'm contenplating just `MitM`'ing myself to decrypt it :P

Comment: @Zsub do you think it makes sense? If it's not public it might be changed any time. However it's a good/useful practical experience :)

Comment: I've dumped it and the web service Xcode uses seems straightforward enough.  I used the Charles proxy, which is able to inspect HTTPS traffic if you install (and trust!) the appropriate certificate.  It's just XML over HTTP.  As Xcode uses this API, Apple will have to maintain compatibility for as long as they want those versions of Xcode to work properly.  Having taken a closer look, I'd prefer this over scraping the HTML.

Comment: @Jim were you able to use the interface with some scripting language? It would be nice if you can share the specs ;)

Answer (score 6):

[Spaceship](https://github.com/fastlane/spaceship) provides access to he developer portal API, no web scraping!

Answer (score 3):

Use [cupertino](https://github.com/nomad/cupertino) ruby script

There is a branch instead as the main one has not been updated since the portal is changed.

https://github.com/MatthewMaker/cupertino

Comment: Thanks. I use this one for a while. BTW fixes from the repo you mention were merged into original https://github.com/nomad/cupertino repo few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following solution:

- create a special repo which has **only** up to date profiles (I know there is still human factor but I have not found better solution at the moment)
- checout the repo with profiles before a build and copy it to the `/User/$USER/Library/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`
- `grep` to find a profile hash and pass the hash as a build option (e.g

`xcodebuild -target ${TargetName} -sdk "${TARGET_SDK}" -configuration "Ad Hoc" "CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY[sdk=iphoneos*]=${PROFILE_NAME}" "PROVISIONING_PROFILE=${grep results}"`

)

The solution works for me but still has some issues.

Comment: But this does not answer the question how to do a scripted download of the current Profiles from Apple.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the easiest way to do this is to use [sigh](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/sigh/) which is part of [fastlane](https://docs.fastlane.tools/). On Mac just run the following:

```sh
brew install fastlane
fastlane sigh download_all
```

This will download all of the profiles for your account.

You can also download an individual app by passing in a bundle ID:

```sh
fastlane sigh -a com.my.app
```

It will create one if it doesn't exist and will repair it if it's expired or invalid.

If you want to do this without the "interactive" mode of entering your username and password you can just set the `FASTLANE_USER` and `FASTLANE_PASSWORD` environment variables to your Apple account email and password (and `FASTLANE_TEAM_ID` if you have multiple teams).