# Can iOS Provisioning Profiles be renewed from the command-line?

Tags: ios, build-automation

I've got a build script that I will be running on a Mac mini as a build server. It should work just fine but I still need to renew and get the latest provisioning profile manually. Is there a way this can be done from the command-line?

Comment: possible duplicate of [API to get a provisioning profile from Apple dev site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306827/api-to-get-a-provisioning-profile-from-apple-dev-site)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the *Automator* to record and create an app that renews the provisioning profiles.

The steps are (copying from the *Watch Me Do* list):

- Click Xcode in Dock (make sure to pin XCode to the doc)
- Click the "Window" menu
- Organizer
- Click the "Refresh" button
- Click the "Log in" button (save the credentials in your key chain)

Then save it to your desktop as *RefreshProvisionProfile.app* (or somewhere else).

To run it from any terminal or from a build script as follows:
**/Users/User_name/Desktop/*RefreshProvisionProfile.app*/Contents/MacOS/Application\ Stub *RefreshProvisionProfile*.app/**

Seems to work for me.

Here is some code we use to identify the profile we want to ship to QA with the project:

```
#Copy profile from $ProfileName
cd "/Users/macbuild/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/"
ProfileFile="`grep -al $ProfileName *.mobileprovision`"
echo "Also copy $ProfileFile to the network"
if cp -fv $ProfileFile /Volumes/shared/Builds/$buildid/
then
    echo "Matching Provisioning Certificate: shared/Builds/$buildid/$ProfileFile"
fi
```

For XCode 5.0.2 the order is as follows:

- Click the **Xcode** menu, choose **Preferences**
- Select the **Accounts** tab
- Select an *Apple ID* in the left pane
- Click the **View Details...** button in the right pane
- Click the **Refresh** button at the bottom left of the new window

Comment: What about deleting bad provisioning profiles? I often have trouble where the refresh process sends me provisioning profiles which are invalid which I have to delete before I proceed.

Comment: @Brennan, not easy solution for that yet, but deleting them from Apple's developer's site prevents you from having to deal with it more than once per invalidation. Seems that there's an answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712895/validate-certificate-and-provisioning-profile - but you'll need Ruby which I have not yet installed.

Comment: The trouble I have is abandoned teams on the developer portal which still lists me as a team member. I am not sure if I can easily leave those teams.

Comment: @Brennan, it's possible to grep the provisioning profiles - they are mostly readbale text. Maybe with some luck you'll be able to identify something unique in the bad ones, and then delete them. I added some code to my answer, since it doesn't format well in the comments.

Comment: In Xcode 7.3 I don't think there is any way to in the GUI to see that a provision profile should be refreshed, and no button Refresh on a ProvisionProfile.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think so. Pretty sure you have to do that via the Web Portal.