# Command line way to test iOS mobile provisioning profile is still valid?

Tags: ios, shell, jenkins, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

One reason a profile may be invalid according to Developer.Apple.com is that the certificate is now obsolete. Checking for the cert is covered in this post: [Validate certificate and provisioning profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712895/validate-certificate-and-provisioning-profile)

I am interested more generally, how to test if the profile is now stale. Right now I find out with a very long delay, so it is impossible to decipher the cause of the invalidation. If I could run this command, say each time my build job runs on Jenkins, then I could be better able to failure analyze by noting exactly when the shift occurred from valid to  invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a simple gem install, this can be achieved using fastlane's spaceship api, and the Developer portal doc shows an exact example.

```
broken_profiles = Spaceship.provisioning_profile.all.find_all do |profile|
  # the below could be replaced with `!profile.valid?`, which takes longer but also verifies the code signing identity
  (profile.status == "Invalid" or profile.status == "Expired")
end
```

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/spaceship/docs/DeveloperPortal.md

Answer (score 4):

You can write a shell script that will loop through the files, grab the date from the mobileprovision file, and check it against the current date.

```
#!/bin/sh

for provisioning_profile in ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/*.mobileprovision;
do
    printf "Checking ${provisioning_profile}... "

    # pull the expiration date from the plist
    expirationDate=`/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Print :ExpirationDate' /dev/stdin <<< $(security cms -D -i "${provisioning_profile}")`

    # convert it to a format we can use to see if it is in the past (YYYYMMDD)
    read dow month day time timezone year <<< "${expirationDate}"
    ymd_expiration=`date -jf"%a %e %b %Y" "${dow} ${day} ${month} ${year}" +%Y%m%d`

    # compare it to today's date
    ymd_today=`date +%Y%m%d`

    if [ ${ymd_today} -ge ${ymd_expiration} ];
    then
        echo "${provisioning_profile} EXPIRED"
    fi

done
```

You can use the security command and plist buddy to extract the ExpirationDate from the file. Then for simplicity I just convert that date to a easily comparable format (YYYMMDD) and compare it to today's date in the same format. I print out the profiles that it found.

Ideally, you would want to change it to give a warning some time in advance (I'd recommend 30 days).  That way you have time to regenerate the profile and give you time to build with a new profile and get it to your test devices.

Comment: Ty, this is very helpful! My biggest problem is with the invalidations, though, not the expirations. Xcode/apple keeps invalidating my profiles every so often. The in/valid info I think is only stored on apple's server.